# Codeigniter fetch records from table undefined variable error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to fetch data from a table, I created a controller, model and view but when I try to open view, I am getting two errors one is `Message: Undefined variable: u_list` and another one is `Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` I am using CodeIgniter 3.1.9

Controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class UserFetch extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('userinsert');
    }

    public function index() {  
     $data['u_list']=$this->userinsert->select();
     $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

Model

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class UserInsert extends CI_Model {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function user_insert($data) {
        $this->db->insert('users', $data);
    }

    public function select() {  
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query; 
    } 
}
?>
```

View

```
<tbody>
    <?php
        foreach ($u_list as $row) {  
    ?>
    <tr>  
    <td><?php echo $row->first_name;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->last_name;?></td>
    </tr>  
    <?php }
    ?>
</tbody>
```

Help me with this guys

Comment: are you sure you are using correct view?

Comment: Yes I am, I am loading a correct view

Comment: go in you view and dump like this `var_dump($this->_ci_cached_vars);` tell me what are you getting there

Comment: @SyedArifIqbal Got this `array (size=0) empty`

Comment: try something like this if this works `$this->load->view('dashboard', ['u_list' => $this->userinsert->select()]);`

Comment: No, it's not working

Comment: than i check your double check your view if you are loading correctly. and also please add your directory tree view if possible.

Comment: @SyedArifIqbal Insertion of data is working perfectly but getting problem on fetching only

Comment: you are getting undefined variable first. so it's easy to solve second after first

Answer (score 2):

Replace your function select with below code

```
public function select() {  
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    return $query->result(); 
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Try to debug by  print_r($data['u_list']); exit; in your controller

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `result` in MODEL

```
 public function select() {  
        $query = $this->db->get('users')->result();
        return $query; 
    }
```

Comment: just print  $query and tell em what you getting?

Comment: Where? in view part?

Comment: check in model part

Comment: Checked the model part nothing printed by `$query`

Comment: So now just echo $this->db->last_query(); die; before return. and use that printed query in your mysql DB.

Comment: Still didn't get anything, strange

Answer (score 1):

```
// use this function in your module 
public function select() {  
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
      $query = mysqli_fetch_all($query );
        return $query; 
    }    

 <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach ($data['u_list'] as $row) {  
        ?>
        <tr>  
        <td><?php echo $row['first_name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['last_name'];?></td>
        </tr>  
        <?php }
        ?>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Same error `Message: Undefined variable: data` and `Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: public function select() {  
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
      $query = mysqli_fetch_all($query );
        return $query; 
    }

Answer (score 0):

in your model ...

```
public function select() {  
      $this->db->select("*"); 
      $this->db->from('users');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: public function select() {  
      $this->db->select("*"); 
      $this->db->from('users');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      if ($query->num_rows() >0 ) {
           return $query->result();
    }

}